# Visual Studio 2013 : Sign In page won't load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, licensing

I apologize for such a mundane question but I cannot sign into my Visual Studio IDE. When I click the sign-in button I get a message saying "This page can't be displayed. This has been the case since I originally downloaded the program so I just never signed in, but now my license has expired and I have to sign in to keep using it. So I'm effectively locked out of my project.

If anyone has had this issue I would greatly appreciate any advice.
I tried, uninstalling / reinstalling; I tried installing express instead of community. I tried googling for this problem or similar problems, I tried posting on the mscv forums, all to no avail. I feel like I've tried everything!

I thank you in advance for any advice anyone can offer. Even if there is a way to wipe clean and start a new 30 day trial I would be thrilled. I had hoped re-installing would allow that but no luck.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! It was a simple matter of enabling TSL in the browser security settings.

Comment: Almost the same for me, I had to activate SSL 2.0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. This is what fixed it for me.
1. Open IE and enter the URL https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com
2. Sign in through IE
3. Try the Sign In button in Visual Studio again. It magically comes up.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. I actually get the same page can't be displayed message when I try and open that link in IE. So I guess the problem is with the browser. Thanks, I'll see if I can do anything to the browser that will help.